# required attribute not working in form in codeigniter php

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, codeigniter-3

i have a shopping website in codeigniter, where  have a product details page, in which user should select the color and size which is mandotory before adding to cart, so i did the following code:

```html
<form action="">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="size" id="rad" value="xssize" required>

  <select name="color" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" required>
    <option selected disabled>Select Item Color</option>
    <option value="RED">RED</option>
  </select>

  <a id="postGender" type="submit" href="<?php echo site_url('homecontroller/buy/'.$product->id); ?>" class="btn btn-to-cart"><span class="bag"></span><span>Add To cart</span><div class="clearfix"></div></a>

</form>
```

however, the required attriubute is not working, user is able to click the add to cart button, can anyone please tell me how to fix it, thanks n advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this.

```php
<form action="<?php echo site_url('homecontroller/buy/'.$product->id); ?>">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="size" id="rad" value="xssize" required>

  <select name="color" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" required>
    <option selected disabled>Select Item Color</option>
    <option value="RED">RED</option>
  </select>

  <button id="postGender" type="submit" class="btn btn-to-cart"><span class="bag"></span><span>Add To cart</span><div class="clearfix"></div></button>

</form>
```

Should work